# Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

I migrated my project to androidX and added in the pubspec file,
fluttery_audio: ^ 0.0.4

and I encountered this error How can I solve it?

this is the log of flutter run -v

```dart
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:24:3)
#1      _buildGradleProjectV2 (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:509:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      buildGradleProject (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:346:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      buildApk (package:flutter_tools/src/android/apk.dart:34:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      AndroidDevice.startApp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart:422:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      FlutterDevice.runHot (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:371:54)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      HotRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/run_hot.dart:253:39)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:489:37)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:508:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:413:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#12     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#13     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#14     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#15     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:152:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're either using an old version of fluttery_audio, or your project has not been correctly migrated to AndroidX, I manually migrated mine when I had a similar error. Use this https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility . Hope that helps

Comment: thank you for your reponce but I solve this problem by adding:
- **compileSdkVersion 28**
- **targetSdkVersion 16**
- **minSdkVersion 16**

Comment: can I ask a question for you?

Comment: I use the flutter_audio plugin at first it works properly then I encountered this error which stops my application completely
`Android -> Flutter: onBufferingUpdate()
E/AndroidRuntime(29083): FATAL EXCEPTION: AudioPlayer
E/AndroidRuntime(29083): java.lang.RuntimeException: Methods marked with @UiThread must be executed on the main thread. Current thread: AudioPlayer`